# Sync your settings not available on Windows 10 Creators Update

Tags: windows-10

I've got two Windows 10 machines sitting side by side on my desk. Both:

- Are joined to the same domain
- Are logged in as the same domain user
- Have the same Microsoft Account added under Settings/Accounts/Email & app accounts under both Email, calendar and contacts, and Accounts used by other apps.

The difference between the two machines is that one is running Anniversary Update (14393.969) and the other is running Creators Update (15063.11).

The AU machine, the user can go to Settings/Accounts/Sync your settings and everything is enabled and the user can turn on the Sync settings option.

On the CU machine, when the user goes to that same location, everything is disabled, and there is a message: "Some Windows features are only available if you are using a Microsoft account or work account." But as far as I can tell I am using *both* a Microsoft account and a work (domain) account.

Any idea why there would be a difference, or how I can enable the settings sync on the CU machine?

**Update:** I've now upgraded my syncing machine to Creator's Update and it still has that page enabled. So now my two machines are on the same version, one has that page enabled, one doesn't.

Comment: ""Some Windows features are only available if you are using a Microsoft account or work account." - This means you have a required setting in order to enable this, specifically disabled, verify all your settings.  The message is used interchangably with not having the permission due to a group policy and being unable to do it because of some other setting (that must be enabled) being disabed

Comment: FYI, you are using a work account but __not__ a Microsoft account. These two are mutually exclusive.

Comment: Have you had a look in the built-in feedback app? That's the "issue tracker" that they make use of

Comment: **Cannot reproduce:** Windows 10.0.14393.969 Enterprise edition, logged in with a domain account, have added Microsoft accounts as described. I don't have sync. How can I? Sync with where?

Comment: @FleetCommand The settings sync is under Settings/Accounts/Sync your settings. I've now upgraded my syncing machine to Creator's Update and it still has that page enabled. So now my two machines are on the same version, one has that page enabled, one doesn't.

Comment: @Tim Yep. That's the one I am talking about. It is disabled in my PC.

Comment: There is a bug, Please up vote the bug.. https://aka.ms/Yut38u Fresh Install of Creators Update is ruing this feature.

Comment: Glad to know I'm not crazy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This finally received a response from Microsoft via the Feedback Hub. The link to the particular feedback hub item is here: https://aka.ms/yut38u but I'll copy/paste the answer in case people can't see that:

> In the Windows 10 Anniversary Update, domain joined users who
>   connected their Microsoft Account (MSA) could roam settings and data
>   between Windows devices.  Many IT Pros told us that this functionality
>   was not consistent with their policies for managing information owned
>   by the organization. They did not want their PCs roaming to an
>   individual’s personal cloud. A group policy to prevent users from
>   connecting their MSAs did and does exist, but this setting also
>   prevents users from easily accessing their personal Microsoft
>   services.  To address IT Pro concerns, we removed the ability for
>   domain joined machines to roam with an MSA.  Enterprises can still
>   enable Enterprise State Roaming with Azure Active Directory.

I guess this is one of those things where my first machine was grandfathered in to the page since it was already enabled before the CU upgrade.